# Text-based RPG Repeating Damage Done

Tags: python

I'm a novice programmer working on a text-based RPG, and for some reason, when the enemy is hit with an arrow when you choose the bowman class, it does the same amount of damage multiple times when it is supposed to do random damage each time, and it doesn't subtract the enemy's health by the damage every time. My code is pretty messy, but please be patient. Also, if you have any advice for me in general, please let me know.

```
  while action == "attack":
        if player_class == "warrior":
            enemy_damage = 30
            enemy_health = enemy_health - enemy_damage
        elif player_class == "bowman":
            target_general = randint(1, 3)
            if target_general == 1:
                action = input(f"You shot to the left of the {enemy}. What will you do now? Attack, evade or run?")
            elif target_general == 2:
                target_specific = randint(1, 5)
                if target_specific == 5:
                    enemy_damage = "way too much"
                    enemy_health = 0
                    print("Critical hit!")
                else:
                    enemy_damage = target_specific * 10
                    enemy_health = enemy_health - enemy_damage
            else:
                action = input(f"You shot to the right of the {enemy}. What will you do now? Attack, evade or run?")
        if enemy_health < 0:
            enemy_health = 0
        if enemy_health == 0:
            player_gold = player_gold + treasure
            print(f"You defeated the {enemy}! You found {treasure} gold.")
            action = leave()
        elif action == "attack" and enemy_damage != 0:
            action = input(f"You attacked the {enemy}, and did {str(enemy_damage)} damage. The enemy has {enemy_health} health left. What will you do now?Attack, evade or run?")
```

Comment: I think you are going to have to give us a little more to reproduce the problem, nothing is jumping out at me I do notice you only remove enemy health if target_general==2.... general critique: you should probably refactor to be some functions or even character classes...

Comment: what is action = leave() ? Everything else looks fine...

Comment: @Grady Player Thank you. Should I post the whole program? It's 121 lines long so far.

Comment: @Mars leave () just prints "You left the room", and turns action into ""

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Vincent. Concerning your second question about advice in general. SO has an area for Code Review. I recommend posting this question there as well. You will get some really great advice on how to clean it up. This isn't really the area for that.

Comment: PS, you should try to include *runnable* code and output logs in your post. The answer by @SteveJ (deleted), is what let me see what the problem was in a split second!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.
You're not resetting `enemy_damage`, so after the first successful attack, even if you miss on the second shot, you will print the missed message, then the damage message.

```
#This message is turn 1
You attacked the Thor, and did 10 damage. The enemy has 460 health left. What will you do now?Attack, evade or run?attack  
#this message is turn 2
You shot to the left of the Thor. What will you do now? Attack, evade or run?attack  
#this message is ALSO turn 2
You attacked the Thor, and did 10 damage. The enemy has 460 health left. What will you do now?Attack, evade or run?attack
```

Throw this in:

```
while action == "attack":
    enemy_damage = 0 # Reset the damage every turn
    ### The rest
```